# Android: dialog started by ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE destroy the previous activity

Tags: java, android

I want to enable bluetooth with the following code from an intent service:

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(enableBtIntent);
```

The logic around my application is:

Activity A launch Activity B which launch this ENABLE_REQUEST.

I tried to launch this request from a service and after even within Activity B itself, but Activity B is always destroy and Activity A comes foreground.

Here's the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ClassifierActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />


    <service
        android:name=".audio.SpeechRecognitionService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:description = "@string/speech_recognition_service_description"
        />

    <service
        android:name=".interaction.SmartObjectInteractionService"
        android:exported="false"
        />
```

I couldn't find any solution!
P.S. Activity B has a Camera Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using *startActivityForResult* instead of startActivity

Comment: Thank you, but i missed a finish() method call... However from a service i can't call the StartActivityForResult method.

In this case is the best practice create an intent on the Service and capture it with a Broadcast Receiver in the Activity so i can call it from there?